# IndexedDB success vs ungradeneeded race

Tags: javascript, concurrency, event-handling, indexeddb

I open indexedDB with new version number

```
var R = indexedDB.open("myDB", 2); // <- new version
R.onupgradeneeded = longRunningFunction;
R.onsuccess = longRunningFunction2;
```

Now I need to run a function when both long running functions finish. What code pattern is appropriate for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use promises or callbacks. Wait for the success event to fire, do its work, and then resolve a promise or call a callback. Then you can do something after that promise resolves or when the callback is called.

Edit, here is a crude example:

```js
function myOpenIndexedDB(name, version, onupgradeneeded) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var request = indexedDB.open(name, version);
    request.onupgradeneeded = onupgradeneeded;
    request.onsuccess = () => resolve(request.result);
    request.onerror = () => reject(request.error);
  });  
}

function myOnUpgradeNeeded(event) {
  console.log('Performing database upgrade');
  const openRequest = event.target;

  // just to demonstrate
  const versionChangeTransaction = openRequest.transaction;
  versionChangeTransaction.oncomplete = () => {
    console.log('The version change transaction completed ' + 
      'which basically means the upgradeneeded handler completed');
  };
}

async function main() {
  console.log('Connecting to database');
  const indexedDbConn = await myOpenIndexedDB('myDb', 2, myOnUpgradeNeeded);
  console.log('Connected to database', indexedDbConn.name);

  // Do more stuff
  await runSomeQuery(indexedDbConn);
}

// Run the example
main().catch(console.error);
```

#### Citations

For more information, see the light-green highlighted block in

- https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#upgrade-transaction-construct
- https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#factory-interface steps 6 and 7

Comment: Is success event guaranteed to fire before or after upgradeneeded event?

Comment: The success event will only fire after the upgradeneeded event.

Comment: That would mean that my `longRunningFunction2` will run in serial after `longRunningFunction`, which would be nice, but I haven't found any authoritative (W3, MDN) statement about this. Can you please quote your source in your answer?

Comment: I added a citation